# Getting error in showing the data in RecyclerView in android using retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am getting the detail data of login user in my application and I am showing some data correctly but I have multiple lists of data like user awards data, user education data, user qualification data, etc... I want this data to display in RecyclerView .... [image: This is the image which describes that in which way I want to show my data]

here is the code where I am doing this in my profile activity... this is where I am calling the Rest API in my profile activity `onCrate()` Method

```
  RetrofitClientLogin user = DatabaseUtil.getInstance().getUser();

        if (user != null && SharedPreferenceUtil.getBoolen(this, Constants.ISUSERLOGGEDIN)) {
            int user_id = DatabaseUtil.getInstance().getUser().getData().getID();
            showProgressDialog("Loading...");
            RetrofitUtil.createProviderAPI().getUserProfile(user_id , "profile_data").enqueue(getUserProfile(this));

        }
```

and here is where the API code is written

```
public static Callback<ProviderModel> getUserProfile(final onDataloadlistner listener) {

        return new Callback<ProviderModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProviderModel> call, Response<ProviderModel> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        listener.onProfileLoaded(response.body());
                    }
                } else {
                    listener.onError(Constants.Errors.FAILED,"Something went wrong. Please try again later!");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProviderModel> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                listener.onError(Constants.Errors.FAILED,t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        };
```

and here I am getting and showing the simple data of my profile activity

```
 @Override
    public void onProfileLoaded(ProviderModel item) {
        userData = item;
        if (item != null) {
            smf.getMapAsync(this);
            //         setDataToSpinners();
            shortDescription.setText(item.getAll().getDescription());
            firstName.setText(item.getAll().getFirstName());
            lastName.setText(item.getAll().getLastName());
            //          tagLine.setText(item.getTagLine());
            address.setText(item.getAddress());
            Fax.setText(item.getFax());
            phone.setText(item.getPhone());
            website.setText(item.getWebsite());
            Tagline.setText(item.getAll().getTagline());
            postalcode.setText(item.getAll().getZip());
            longitude.setText(item.getAll().getLongitude());
            latitude.setText(item.getAll().getLatitude());
            professional_statement.setText(item.getAll().getProfessionalStatements());




        }
        hideProgressDialog();
    }
```

can anyone please help me how to display the list data like this in my application

here is the response of api

```
{
id: 294,
author_url: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/fitness-center/better/",
verified: "on",
img_url: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/7-270x270.jpg",
directory_type: "121",
directory_type_name: "Fitness Center",
directoty_type_slug: "fitness-center",
directory_type_url: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/provider-category/fitness-center/",
name: "Better Bodies",
address: "54 Park Rd, London NW4 3PH, UK",
phone: "50 235 856843",
fax: "202-555-0131",
email: "better@themographics.com",
website: "www.company.com",
category_color: "#3498db",
review_data: {
reviews: 1,
percentage: 80,
average_rating: 4,
by_ratings: [
{
rating: 0,
total: 0
},
{
rating: 0,
total: 0
},
{
rating: 0,
total: 0
},
{
rating: 4,
total: 1
},
{
rating: 0,
total: 0
}
]
},
rating: "4.0",
likes: "1",
all: {
items_privacy: {
education: "disabled",
experience: "disabled",
reviews: "enabled",
bookings: "enabled",
insurance: "enabled",
teams: "enabled",
awards: "enabled",
price_list: "enabled",
articles: "disabled",
qa: "enabled",
profile_banner: "enabled",
favorites: "enabled",
business_hours: "enabled"
},
user_type: "professional",
full_name: "Better Bodies",
directory_type: "121",
video_url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/0aNNYEUARAk",
user_gallery: [
{
thumb: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-10-150x150.jpg",
full: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-10.jpg",
id: 212
},
{
thumb: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-09-150x150.jpg",
full: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-09.jpg",
id: 211
},
{
thumb: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-08-150x150.jpg",
full: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-08.jpg",
id: 210
},
{
thumb: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-07-150x150.jpg",
full: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-07.jpg",
id: 209
},
{
thumb: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-05-150x150.jpg",
full: "https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/img-05.jpg",
id: 207
}
],
userprofile_media: "284",
facebook: "#",
twitter: "#",
linkedin: "#",
pinterest: "#",
google_plus: "#",
tumblr: "#",
instagram: "#",
skype: "better-bodies",
user_address: "54 Park Rd, London NW4 3PH, UK",
contact_form: "on",
profile_status: "active",
tagline: "Fitness Center",
phone_number: "50 235 856843",
fax: "202-555-0131",
languages: [
"English",
"Arabic",
"Danish"
],
address: "54 Park Rd, London NW4 3PH, UK",
latitude: "51.577259",
longitude: "-0.232151",
location: "batley",
zip: "N7",
verify_user: "on",
privacy: {
appointments: "on",
phone: "on",
email: "on",
contact_form: "on"
},
awards: [
{
name: "Testing",
date: "16/1/1900",
date_formated: "20 Nov, 2018",
description: "hello testing"
},
{
name: "Testing 2",
date: "26/1/1900",
date_formated: "20 Nov, 2018",
description: "hello testing 2"
},
{
name: "hello",
date: "3/1/1900",
date_formated: "20 Nov, 2018",
description: "vdjbdvd"
},
{
name: "body builder",
date: "6/1/1900",
date_formated: "03 Dec, 2018",
description: "very nice experience"
}
],
education: [
{
title: "Bachelor of Medicine, Bachelor of Surgery",
institute: "Medical School - New York University",
start_date: "2011-01-05",
end_date: "2013-01-05",
start_date_formated: "Jan,2011",
end_date_formated: "Jan,2013",
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur._x000D_"
},
{
title: "Bachelor of Medical Sciences",
institute: "Medical School - New York University",
start_date: "2013-01-05",
end_date: "2014-01-05",
start_date_formated: "Jan,2013",
end_date_formated: "Jan,2014",
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur._x000D_"
},
{
title: "New York University, Residency in Internal Medicine",
institute: "Medical School - New York University",
start_date: "2014-01-05",
end_date: "2015-01-05",
start_date_formated: "Jan,2014",
end_date_formated: "Jan,2015",
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
},
{
title: "bscs",
institute: "uos lahore",
start_date: "13/1/1900",
end_date: "25/8/1900",
start_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
end_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
description: "hello friendzzz"
},
{
title: "bscs",
institute: "uos lahore",
start_date: "13/1/1900",
end_date: "25/8/1900",
start_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
end_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
description: "hello friendzzz"
},
{
title: "bscs",
institute: "uos lahore",
start_date: "13/1/1900",
end_date: "25/8/1900",
start_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
end_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
description: "hello friendzzz"
},
{
title: "vhbv",
institute: "vuhb",
start_date: "11/1/1900",
end_date: "27/1/1900",
start_date_formated: "Nov,1900",
end_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
description: "gibcffi"
},
{
title: "bzieb",
institute: "bssbd",
start_date: "18/1/1900",
end_date: "19/1/1900",
start_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
end_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
description: "bdksbdnd"
},
{
title: "bzieb",
institute: "bssbd",
start_date: "18/1/1900",
end_date: "19/1/1900",
start_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
end_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
description: "bdksbdnd"
},
{
title: "title is here",
institute: "institute",
start_date: "10-10-2018",
end_date: "10-10-2018",
start_date_formated: "Oct,2018",
end_date_formated: "Oct,2018",
description: "this is my content"
},
{
title: "title is here",
institute: "institute",
start_date: "10-10-2018",
end_date: "10-10-2018",
start_date_formated: "Oct,2018",
end_date_formated: "Oct,2018",
description: "this is my content"
},
{
title: "title is here 3",
institute: "institute 3",
start_date: "10-10-2018",
end_date: "10-10-2018",
start_date_formated: "Oct,2018",
end_date_formated: "Oct,2018",
description: "this is my content 3"
}
],
experience: [
{
title: "Lecturer, Department of gastroenterology_x000D_",
company: "Co-ed/Women/Boys_x000D_",
start_date: "2010-05-07_x000D_",
end_date: "2012-07-17_x000D_",
start_date_formated: "Jan,1970",
end_date_formated: "Jan,1970",
description: "The Cardiovascular and Respiratory Systems category covers resources concerned with all aspects of cardiovascular and thoracic surgery and respiratory diseases. Topics include circulation, cardiovascular technology and measurement, cardiovascular pharmacology and therapy, hypertension, heart and lung transplantation, arteries, arteriosclerosis, thrombosis, angiology, perfusion, stroke, as well as all types of respiratory and lung diseases._x000D_ _x000D_"
},
{
title: "Sr Consultant at Gastroentology Hospital_x000D_",
company: "Adams State College_x000D_",
start_date: "2012-09-22_x000D_",
end_date: "2014-08-17_x000D_",
start_date_formated: "Jan,1970",
end_date_formated: "Jan,1970",
description: "The Clinical Immunology &amp; Infectious Diseases category covers resources that focus on basic research in clinical and applied allergy, immunology, and infectious disease. Microbiology and virology resources are included in this category as are resources on HIV, AIDS, sexually transmitted diseases (STDs), and hospital infections._x000D_ _x000D_"
},
{
title: "Present Consultant, Department of Gastroenterology at Apollo Hospital_x000D_",
company: "Florida Hospital College of Health Sciences_x000D_",
start_date: "2014-03-27_x000D_",
end_date: "2016-08-03_x000D_",
start_date_formated: "Jan,1970",
end_date_formated: "Jan,1970",
description: "Oral Surgery &amp; Medicine resources are concerned with basic, applied, and clinical aspects of oral infections and diseases, including their epidemiology, diagnosis, treatment, and rehabilitation. Specialties such as oral pathology/biology, oral epidemiology, oral rehabilitation, and oral implants are also included. Facial pain and craniomandibular resources are also covered in this category."
},
{
title: "job",
company: "amento",
start_date: "11/1/1900",
end_date: "13/1/1900",
start_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
end_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
description: "bsjbsvd"
},
{
title: "hcbc",
company: "fxucic",
start_date: "9/1/1900",
end_date: "10/1/1900",
start_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
end_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
description: "n luxhckbic"
},
{
title: "title is here 3",
company: "amento",
start_date: "10-10-2018",
end_date: "10-10-2018",
start_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
end_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
description: "this is my content 3"
},
{
title: "android developer",
company: "amento tech",
start_date: "1/1/1900",
end_date: "30/1/1900",
start_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
end_date_formated: "Nov,2018",
description: "nice job"
}
],
user_profile_specialities: [
"Aerobic Centers",
"Athletic Clubs",
"Dance Centers"
],
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquat enim ad minim veniam. Eascxcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt.",
first_name: "Better",
last_name: "Bodies",
nickname: "better",
schedules: {
mon_start: "08:00",
mon_end: "18:00",
tue_start: "08:00",
tue_end: "018:00",
wed_start: "08:00",
wed_end: "18:00",
thu_start: "08:00",
thu_end: "18:00",
fri_start: "08:00",
fri_end: "18:00",
sat_start: "08:00",
sat_end: "18:00",
sun_start: "08:00",
sun_end: "18:00"
},
time_format: "",
professional_statements: "In just three simple steps, DocDirect will help you find your nearest healthcare setting without having to signup. We aim to facilitate you in finding your right doctor with just three clicks without having to ask around or wander to find your nearest healthcare facility.",
appointments: "on",
phone: "on",
email: "on",
opening_hours: "on",
prices_list: [
{
title: "BIPOLAR DISORDERS",
price: "$225",
description: "Oral Surgery &amp; Medicine resources are concerned with basic, applied, and clinical aspects of oral infections and diseases, including thseir epidemiology, diagnosis, treatment, and rehabilitation. Specialties such as oral pathology/biology, oral epidemiology, oral rehabilitation, and oral implants are also included. Facial pain and craniomandibular resources are also covered in this category."
},
{
title: "Medical/Surgical Unit",
price: "$1500",
description: "Oral Surgery &amp; Medicine resources are concerned with basic, applied, and clinical aspects of oral infections and diseases, including their epidemiology, diagnosis, treatment, and rehabilitation. Specialties such as oral pathology/biology, oral epidemiology, oral rehabilitation, and oral implants are also included. Facial pain and craniomandibular resources are also covered in this category."
},
{
title: "Inpatient Rehabilitation",
price: "$1091.44",
description: "Oral Surgery &amp; Medicine resources are concerned with basic, applied, and clinical aspects of oral infections and diseases, including their epidemiology, diagnosis, treatment, and rehabilitation. Specialties such as oral pathology/biology, oral epidemiology, oral rehabilitation, and oral implants are also included. Facial pain and craniomandibular resources are also covered in this category."
},
{
title: "Cesarean Section Delivery",
price: "$13182.79",
description: "Oral Surgery &amp; Medicine resources are concerned with basic, applied, and clinical aspects of oral infections and diseases, including their epidemiology, diagnosis, treatment, and rehabilitation. Specialties such as oral pathology/biology, oral epidemiology, oral rehabilitation, and oral implants are also included. Facial pain and craniomandibular resources are also covered in this category."
},
{
title: "Pediatric Evaluation – Level 1",
price: "$387.91",
description: "Oral Surgery &amp; Medicine resources are concerned with basic, applied, and clinical aspects of oral infections and diseases, including their epidemiology, diagnosis, treatment, and rehabilitation. Specialties such as oral pathology/biology, oral epidemiology, oral rehabilitation, and oral implants are also included. Facial pain and craniomandibular resources are also covered in this category."
},
{
title: "gzisbs",
price: "vsjsv",
description: "czjsbe"
},
{
title: "gzisbs",
price: "500",
description: "czjsbe"
}
],
user_current_package_expiry: "1559779200",
user_featured: "1546214400",
user_current_package: "34",
userprofile_banner: "1206",
paypal_enable: "on",
paypal_email_id: "wordpress@themographics.com",
stripe_enable: "on",
stripe_secret: "sk_test_GQmHllLhCKNDNx6f0T2cIfTM",
stripe_publishable: "pk_test_v9JXtjELddI4r9unGBShp8TX",
stripe_site: "DocDirect Stripe Payment",
stripe_decimal: "2",
approved_title: "Your Appointment Approved",
confirmation_title: "Your Appointment Confirmation",
cancelled_title: "Your Appointment Cancelled",
thank_you: "Thank you very much for your appointment. We have received your appointment and soon we will let you know regarding your appointment. You will receive a phone call or email regarding to your booking.",
schedule_message: "<span style="color: #5d5955; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">Consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua enim ad minim veniam, <strong>Dr. Jhon Doe</strong> nostrud alitaia exercitation ullamco<strong> Invisalign (invisable braces)</strong> dolor in reprehenderit.</span></span>",
booking_approved: "Hey %customer_name%!<br/> This is confirmation that your booking regarding "%service%" with %provider% has approved.<br/> We are waiting you at "%address%" on %appointment_date% at %appointment_time%.<br/><br/><br/> Sincerely,<br/> %logo%",
booking_confirmed: "Hey %customer_name%!<br/> This is confirmation that you have booked "%service%"<br/> with %provider%.<br/> We will let your know regarding your booking soon.<br/><br/> Thank you for choosing our company.<br/><br/> Sincerely,<br/> %logo%",
booking_cancelled: "Hi %customer_name%!<br/> This is confirmation that your booking regarding "%service%" with %provider% has cancelled.<br/> We are very sorry to process your booking right now.<br/><br/> Sincerely,<br/> %logo%",
currency_symbol: "$",
currency: "USD",
services_cats: {
aerobic-centers: "Aerobic Centers",
yoga-centers: "Yoga Centers",
pilates-centers: "Pilates Centers"
},
wishlist: "",
booking_services: {
aerial-hoop: {
title: "Aerial Hoop",
price: "205",
category: "aerobic-centers"
},
aerial-silks: {
title: "Aerial Silks",
price: "238",
category: "aerobic-centers"
},
jivamukti-yoga: {
title: "Jivamukti Yoga",
price: "150",
category: "yoga-centers"
},
kripalvananda: {
title: "Kripalvananda",
price: "350",
category: "yoga-centers"
},
pontius-pilate: {
title: "Pontius Pilate",
price: "130",
category: "pilates-centers"
},
stott-pilates: {
title: "Stott Pilates",
price: "785",
category: "pilates-centers"
}
},
teams_data: [
333,
334,
335,
336,
337,
340
],
insurance: [ ],
qa: [ ],
articles: [
{
id: 3628,
title: "make body look sexy",
content: "<p>make body look sexy</p> ",
image: null
}
]
}
}
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? what error are you getting while setting this data?

Comment: i am not understanding how to set the list the data in the recyclerview \

Comment: can you please writ a sample code to set awards in the recycler view like this in the picture

Comment: i have added the response of api as well

Comment: you have to get the list from ProviderModel of selected data list and add into local List<Object>.

Comment: @MaulikBaraiya can you write this in sample code for better understanding about it